# ADAL or MSAL for MS Graph for ASP.net application for Azure B2B

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, adal, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks

We are developing the azure B2B Application to invite and access our Asp.net application that is hosted in the Azure. I checked the example https://github.com/Azure/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-b2bportal-web which uses the ADAL for most of the operation. In the example from the above link, the MS Graph using an access token generated from the ADAL, but Microsoft recommends using the MSAL.

My question is Which one we have to use the for MS Graph in the ASP.net Application either ADAL or MSAL.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them can help in handling Ms Graph, but MSAL provides multiple benefits over ADAL including incremental consent, richer single sign-on experiences, support for personal Microsoft accounts, use of standards-based protocols and so on.

Also, MSAL has good [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) available for Ms Graph and easily implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Hari above. Both MSAL/ADAL capable of working with MS Graph. But here's the key differences:

- Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) integrates with the Azure AD for developers (v1.0) endpoint, where MSAL integrates with the Microsoft identity platform (v2.0) endpoint.
- The v1.0 endpoint supports work accounts, but not personal accounts. The v2.0 endpoint is the unification of Microsoft personal accounts and work accounts into a single authentication system. With MSAL you can also get authentications for Azure AD B2C as well.
- So MSAL enables developers to acquire tokens from the Microsoft identity platform endpoint in order to access secured web APIs. These web APIs can be the Microsoft Graph, other Microsoft APIs, third-party web APIs, or your own web API. MSAL is available for .NET, JavaScript, Android, and iOS, which support many different application architectures and platforms.

Hope this helps.